# Query string with dot as decimal separator in C#

Tags: c#, query-string, cultureinfo

I would like to build a query string with a dot as decimal separator but I can not figure out how / where I should use the CultureInfo to convert the comma to the dot in the Account property value.

```
Person person = new()
{
    Name = "Tom",
    Account = 1000.123m,
};

var properties = from p in person.GetType().GetProperties()
                 where p.GetValue(person, null) != null
                 select p.Name.ToLower() + "=" + p.GetValue(person);

Console.WriteLine(String.Join("&", properties.ToArray()));


class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public decimal Account { get; set; }
}
```

Current output: `name=Tom&account=1000,123`

Expected output: `name=Tom&account=1000.123`

I guess there is something to add to  `+ p.GetValue(person)`

Can you help me please? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To format numeric property values using a period instead of a comma for the decimal separator, call [Convert.ToString(Object, IFormatProvider)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=net-8.0#system-convert-tostring(system-object-system-iformatprovider)) and pass the invariant culture as the second argument:

```
using System.Globalization;

// ...

select p.Name.ToLower() + "=" + Convert.ToString(p.GetValue(person), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// or you can use string interpolation:
// select FormattableString.Invariant($"{p.Name.ToLower()}={p.GetValue(person)}");
```

This particular overload of Convert.ToString calls IConvertible.ToString, IFormattable.ToString, or just Object.ToString depending on the interfaces implemented by the value.

---

By the way, for the property name, you should call [String.ToLowerInvariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolowerinvariant?view=net-8.0) instead of ToLower to avoid the Turkish "i" problem: In the `tr-TR` culture, `"I".ToLower()` returns `"ı"` (dotless i) instead of `"i"`. You should also ensure that special characters in the property value are correctly encoded in the query string:

```
select p.Name.ToLowerInvariant() + "=" +
    Uri.EscapeDataString(Convert.ToString(p.GetValue(person), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)!);
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you very much Michael Liu